# send email php with google cloud api

Tags: php, email, google-email-settings-api

I use the following code, that I get it from google's cloud documentation and it is used to send emails. The code works fines and sends email. I got only one small problem. How to make instead of senders email to be displayed the senders name that I want to give.

This is the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
use \google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

try
{
  $message = new Message();
  $message->setSender("sender@gmail.com");

//--- try change the above line to : $message->setSender("my_name <sender@gmail.com>");
//--- but did not work, couldn't even send email when changed it.


  $message->addTo("receiver@me.com");
  $message->setSubject("Example email");
  $message->setTextBody("Hello, world!");
  $message->addAttachment('image.jpg', 'image data', $image_content_id);
  $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
  // ...
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue on the GAE php library that will be fixed in the next release.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10153

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = 'John Doe';
$from = 'john@doe.com';
$message = new Message();
$message->setSender($name.'<'.$from.'>');
```

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10153#c12